# Powershell output for multiple dhcp servers

Tags: powershell, dhcp, mib

I am trying to get the mibinfo for multiple dhcp servers in our infrastructure. My problem is that when i run the command

```
invoke-command -computername $dhcpserver -credential $Cred -scriptblock{netsh dhcp server show mibinfo}
```

I get MIBinfo for all the servers, but i don't get the name of the server in the output. So i need a way where i get the output as

Server1
mibinfo

server2
mibinfo

($dhcpserver has the list of all the dhcp servers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is $dhcpserver an array of strings? I didn't know Invoke-Command could do this...

If so, try this:

```
Foreach ($server in $dhcpserver) { 
    $mibOutput = invoke-command -computername $server -credential $Cred -scriptblock{netsh dhcp server show mibinfo}
    Write-Output "$server $mibOutput"
}
```